# Does couchbase analytics support all N1QL commands?

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

Does Couchbase Analitics supports all N1QL language features? I using workbench to test 2 queries in Query tab and Analytics tab. Query tab executes queries, while in Analytics tab I am getting errors "Syntax error".

Queries:

`1. select * FROM [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as res OFFSET  2`

`2. select [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][1:3] as res;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, SQL++ (aka N1QL for Analytics) and N1QL (aka N1QL for Query) are two different languages.

For your first query, `OFFSET` is not (yet) supported in Analytics without a `LIMIT`.

For the second query, it's looks like you're trying to do something similar to offset/limit, but it looks like the `:` part is not supported in Analytics. I'm not exactly sure if there's an equivalent. You might want to have a peek at the docs page [N1QL for Analytics vs. N1QL for Query](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/analytics/6_n1ql.html).

Answer (score 3):

The array slicing syntax is currently not supported in Couchbase Analytics.
To get the same result today you can use a subquery instead

```
SELECT (SELECT VALUE v FROM [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] v LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1) as res
```